# Disabling button rollover for certain number of frames Flash actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, function, button, event-listener

I'm constructing an area with selectable buttons that transition and appear every 10 frames. During these 10 frame transition periods I don't want the buttons to be selectable and if possible to disable the rollover.

I've tried creating an If statement on the addEventListener so that it only works when currentFrame is 11,21,31 etc but this didn't work. I then also tried the same principal on the function to which the Event Listener relates but still no success.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a listener for the ENTER_FRAME event, and put the if in the callback function.

For example

```
 this.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

 function onEnterFrame (evt:Event):void {
 if (currentFrame == 21) {
       yourButton.enabled = false;
 } else {
       yourButton.enabled = true;
 }

 }
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it doesn't work. I already have an ENTER_FRAME event so it may not have integrated well...

Comment: I didn't test it, the code I've written it's just an example of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 things:

1:
You manually add and remove the listener.
So when you start the transition, the listener is removed,
then when the transition ends, the listener is added.

2:
You make a custom listener which checks for the state of the frame to see whether it should execute its body.

EXAMPLE:

```
public void listener(event:Event) {
    if (event.getSource().stage.getCurrentFrame() == 10) {//This is an example, I don't know whether this specific way will work.
        //Run your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that 1. I have one frame with Actions on which governs the entire document, and 2. when the button is clicked, the frame which is the next destination for the timeline to stop is calculate from the currentFrame, so it is imperative that the button is only clicked on valid frames. How would I make a listener which checks the 'state of the frame' as you mentioned?